# Can't find InkAnalyzer (IAWinFX.dll) in my system

Tags: c#, handwriting-recognition, ink-analyzer

I am working on a handwriting recognition application and want to use InkAnalyzer in it. I have seen an example on youtube which demonstrate the Microsoft Ink and InkAnalyzer. But the problem is I am not able to find the dll for InkAnalyzer (IAWinFX.dll).

here is the link of the video where I have seen [this sample](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbxmmOKBeoE).

In the video it is shown that this dll is located at this path of the system : **C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Tablet PC\v1.7\IAWinFX.dll**

But I can only find folder named v6.0 in Tablet PC folder in my system, there is no v1.7 folder. Please let me know how can I install this tablet PC SDK so that I can get this dll.

I have already tried Tablet PC SDK setups but none of them gave me that dll.

Comment: Don't use this on operating systems later than XP: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20039

Comment: But you can see on the youtube link above that this guy is using InkAnalyzer in Windows 7. So this is possible but I don't know how.

Comment: As Hans stated, the IAWinFX.dll is only available if you install the Tablet PC SDK on an XP machine.  If you are using Windows 7, 8, or 10, you will need to try a different approach for handwriting recognition.  I have provided a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502373/wpf-handwriting-net-4-5-windows-8-missing-iawinfx-dll-and-others/30516175#30516175